# php class error handling

Tags: php

```
class Foo {
    private $_bar;

    public function getBar() {
        return $this->_bar;
    }
}
$b = new Foo(); 
$b->xxx(); //xxx is an udefined method.
```

How to enhance the following class to throw a notice if undefined methods is called?

Comment: you can do it like the answer says, but why would you need to do something like that?

Comment: just education :) Thus, i don't know if its good practice ...

Comment: in that case, i think that in the 'standard' object paradigm it isnt. you just need to design your classes in a way that an object will never be asked for a method that doesnt have.
but if you want to learn look for books about object oriented proggraming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Foo {
    private $_bar;

    public function getBar() {
        return $this->_bar;
    }

    public function __call($name, $params)
    {
       throw new Exception("Method $name does not exists!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to define a  the  __call( $methodName , $args )  method.

And throw your own exception from there.

Answer (score 0):

A PHP warning would be thrown like any other time when you call an undefined function. You need to enable it with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: calls to nonexistent methods are actually fatal errors, no matter what the error_reporting level is.

Answer (score 0):

write __call in Class Foo

```
function __call( $functionName, $argumentsArray ) {
      echo "Function $functionName does not exist";
    }
```

[Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call)